# Associar usuário logado com suas informações?

Tags: php, mysql, session

Depois de fazer o "session", como faço para trazer as informações do usuário logado ? eu sei que não é apenas criar uma sessão, preciso trazer informações do usuário como Nome/Nickname, avatar, email etc.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi na sua pergunta o que você deveria é aproveitar o select que você faz para validar o usuário e retorna seus dados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer um select no seu banco de dados recuperando a informação do usuário e assim você poderia setar o objeto ou uma variável da forma que preferir contendo os user em uma sessão dessa forma: `$_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario` e para acessar é quase da mesma forma:

```
$usuario = $_SESSION['usuario']
$usuario->getNome();
$usuario->getEmail();
```

Nesse exemplo eu faço como se eu estivesse setado o objeto de um usuario dentro dá sessão e estou obtendo seus atributos através dos métodos get desse objeto. se você não colocar o objeto de um usuário na sessão e não sabe como acessar basta só dá um `var_dump($variavel)` e ter uma melhor visualização sobre sua variável